# How to make a lead similar to a circular saw

Tags: effects, noise, daw, synthesizer, ambience

How to make a lead like in [Notre-Dame de Paris - La monture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qe9SwIOmv0) at the first 4 seconds?

This sound is similar to a circular saw. It is often used to represent aridity. It's also featured in [The Future Sound Of London - Papua New Guinea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfWMv8Y1V5E#t=0m27) at 0:27

and in Dj Promo - Beat Ya Brain Again at 0:40. It can be very useful for a big beat track.

Tutorials of any DAW can be useful but the target DAW is Audiotool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a electronically generated/synthesised sound. 
You should look into sampling a metal sheet that is bowed by a violin player.
[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nu6ZuJBU7Y) is a very musical example with a saw, but if you take a metal sheet and a bow you'll get a more disharmonic result.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterphone

It sounds like this:

The resonate frequencies are similar to the sample you provided (from what I hear and think :-)

If you do want to synthesise this, I guess you should go for physical models rather than OSCs.

Edit:
Perhaps putting a crash/hit hat through a granulizer (or many, say 1000 granulizers) will also work?
I got this idea from your second sample. It sounds like a lot of sharp stuff with a repeating pattern.